# Changing customerid on project does not update current customer and get invalid location error

Tags: acumatica

I have development project where I am syncing data from another system into Acumicatica projects. Sometimes the customer on the project needs to change.  But when I set project.CustomerId and call graph.Project.Update(project) I get an error Message: Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Customer value 4615 Error: Default Location 'MAIN      ' cannot be found in the system.

When I debug and look at the graph I see that current customer is still looking at the old customer and therefore I suspect thats where location error is coming from as new or old location does not exist on the customer.

Can anybody help in getting the current customer to update without error?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cache.SetValueExt method to update CustomerID. The method raises the FieldUpdating, FieldVerifying, FieldUpdated events, and hopefully will updates your current customer record as well.

```
graph.Project.SetValueExt<PMProject.customerID>(project, newCustomerID);
graph.Project.Update(project);
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked changed the customer and locationid on both project and project task but still got that location main error on saving.  It says on the project task.  I tried the same line setting the project and project task locationid with the customer deflocationid n still same error

Comment: Please update your question with your code, it might help to figure out what is going on.